# How Do I Create A Database And User In Docker Using A Script?

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker

I'm following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017) on how to connect to MS SQL Server using docker.

After running the container you need to connect to do some setup:

```
docker exec -it sql1 "bash"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'YourStrong!Passw0rd'
```

Create a database

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO
```

Then create a user

```
CREATE LOGIN TEST_USER WITH PASSWORD = 'YourStrong!Passw0rd'
GO
QUIT
```

Maybe you want to do a few other things like `sp_addrolemember` to be owner or other some such.

Is it possible to script these steps or combine it into single command?

e.g. run the docker command with the `sqlcmd` as a parameter and the required sql in a file as a parameter to that?

I don't want to compose my own container with these changes in.

Answer (score 1):

For those ending up here who just want a "scriptable" solution, something like this should work (for mssql 2017):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

CONTAINER_NAME="replace-with-something-meaningfull"
SA_PASSWORD="YourStrong!Passw0rd"
DB_NAME="TestDB"

until docker exec -i ${CONTAINER_NAME} /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P ${SA_PASSWORD} -d master -Q "CREATE DATABASE ${DB_NAME}" 2>/dev/null
do
  sleep 2
done

until docker exec -i ${CONTAINER_NAME} /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P ${SA_PASSWORD} -d master -Q "CREATE LOGIN TEST_USER WITH PASSWORD = 'YourStrong!Passw0rd'" 2>/dev/null
do
  sleep 2
done
```

It is by no means perfect but should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can create the desired behavior with custom Dockerfile.
Take a look here https://github.com/mcmoe/mssqldocker

Comment: This is not an answer and should only be a comment as it only gives an idea and does not directly provide a solution. Also, the OP mentions what he does not want to do in his case